# why my code make my window of browser freeze when i use this async in html ? but working fine when i use in component

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I have this method I am calling in template it's not working but when I call it inside component it's working fine. Here is method of component:

```ts
 getDocumentVia(path):Observable<any>{
   return this.api.getDoc('subCategory',path).pipe(map(data=>data.data().name))
 }
```

and here is template side code where I am calling it with async:

```html
  <div *ngIf="item.id" class="flex-1 pl-2">  
        {{getDocumentVia(item.id)|async }}
   </div>
```

its not showing out in template , but its working in component side when i test . and its not showing any error , its freeze the window when i use this code in template

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Errors? Unexpected outputs?

Comment: Note that functions called from the template are called on every "tick", so if it's freezing it's probably because of an infinite loop. You should reorganise your code so it's only called when the id changes, and just expose the observable to the template.

Comment: yeah i am using it inside a loop , but loop is not infinite , and i confirmed that

Answer (score 1):

The expressions in the template are evaluated on every change detection. If you call a function there, like this

```
<div *ngIf="item.id" class="flex-1 pl-2">  
    {{ getDocumentVia(item.id)|async }}
</div>
```

then the *function* will be called on every change detection. From the symptoms I'm assuming that the change detection triggers change detection - which creates an infinite loop.

Solution - in the template don't call functions doing complex stuff (simple getters are OK). Switching change detection strategy to "on push" could also work.

Comment: or can i create a pipe for this is that will be ok ?

Comment: With non-trivial logic like here, the best answer is simply "don't". Do the fetching in the TS part, and let the template just take care of displaying the fetched data.

Comment: so i can create the child component to handle this . fetch and then show , is that way will be correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Example code of answer from @mbojko

In service file - grpcgreeter.service.ts

```
   async getSomeDataFromGrpcServer():Promise<GrpcReturnType> {
    //Call the Server with some hard coded values
    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.setQuery('query');
    searchRequest.setEmailId('my@emailId.com');
   
    const call = this.searchService.search(searchRequest, {}, (err: grpcWeb.RpcError, response: SearchResponse) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("GRPC Error",err);
        this.responseData.error =err
        return;
      }
      this.responseData.data = response.getSearchResponse()
    }
    );
    var result = await call.on('status', (status: grpcWeb.Status) => {
      if (status.metadata) {
        console.log("Course Component.ts ->status.metadata", status.metadata);
      }
    });
    return this.responseData
  }
```

In component.ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {GrpcGreeterService} from "./grpc-greeter.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'courses' ,// <courses>
    template: `
         <h2>{{"Title :" + getTitle()}}</h2>
         <div>{{courses}}</div>
         <ul>
            <li  *ngFor= "let course of courses">
               {{course}}
            </li>
         </ul>
    `
})
export class CoursesComponent{
    title = "List of Courses"
    courses: string[];
    grpcServer;


    constructor(service: GrpcGreeterService){
       this.courses = []
       this.grpcServer = service
       setInterval(()=> { this.getCourseData() }, 2 * 1000);
    }
  
    getTitle(){
         return this.title
    }

    async getCourseData(){
        let response = await this.grpcServer.getSomeDataFromGrpcServer()
        if (response.error){
            console.log("Error Response from GRPC Server call - Details ",response.error)
        }
        console.log("Response from GRPC Server",response)
        this.courses.push(response.data)
    }

}
```

Instead, if you try to do async in template like below; it was running into infinite loop

```
  <li  *ngFor= "let course of getCourseData()|async">
```